# Allow users to manage only comments on their own posts

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, comments, admin

I want to restrict contributer and author users to seeing and manageing comments only on their own posts.

I have tried the following filter with no success.

```
//Manage Your Own Comments Only
    function myplugin_comments_thisuseronly( $wp_query ) {
if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/edit-comments.php' ) !== false ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
        global $current_user;global $wpdb;
        $usersposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_author = %s", $current_user->id) );
        $wp_query->set('comment_post_ID', array($usersposts));
    }
}
}
```

add_filter('parse_query', 'myplugin_comments_thisuseronly' );

I also tried

```
$wp_query->set('comment_post_ID__in', array($usersposts));
```

Comment: Do you need this in the front-end, back-end or both?

Comment: Back end. I will have a large number of users. They really should not be able to manage or even see comments on anyone else's posts in the dashboard. It's crack this or disable comments basically :)

Comment: Darn. Front end would have been relatively simple, back end is tough.

I am assuming you found some code to display only the authors own posts and modified it for comments? Sorry to say, but this is - even with more modification - not going to work.

It would also be relatively simple to list only comments made by one user. But listing comments on all of an author's posts and not of others is a tough nut to crack.

The problem lies in the fact that the _wp_comments_ table does include the post ID of the commented post, but not its author.

Comment: Hence the only solution I see would be removing the regular Comments section from wp-admin for authors and contributors and implementing your own via a plugin, that does not make use of wordpress hooks but directly fetches comments from the _wp_comments_ table. It would have to grab all post IDs of the specific authors posts in an array from the _wp_posts_ table, then fetch all comments related to those IDs from _wp_comments_ and then display 'em in wp-admin. That can be done, but unfortunately is beyond the scope of Q&A and in the realm of contracted work.

Comment: Hoping, for your sake that I'm wrong (which I am very doubtful about): I'd ask the same question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, it seems near impossible. I've tried a couple of different approaches but nothing. I am pretty determined to crack it though, and have two weeks to keep going back to it and worrying it, because it seems to me that it would be pretty useful to more people than me. Your alternative comments approach is definitely one possibility.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I figured this out.

First, the user needs to have a role with permission to edit published posts AND to moderate comments. The latter is **not** standard for authors/contributors.

Then, by filtering the query which gets the comments (using comments_clauses) and adding a join you can show only comments for posts by the currently logged in user.

```
function my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user($clauses) {
if (is_admin()) {
    global $user_ID, $wpdb;
    $clauses['join'] = ", wp_posts";
    $clauses['where'] .= " AND wp_posts.post_author = ".$user_ID." AND wp_comments.comment_post_ID = wp_posts.ID";
};
return $clauses;
};
// Ensure that editors and admins can moderate all comments
if(!current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
add_filter('comments_clauses', 'my_plugin_get_comment_list_by_user');
}
```

Works perfectly. The changes to roles may not suit every setup, but as it happens it does work for me on this site.